# Bad Karma and Success

Tags: karma, dharma

Many people become rich, successful and powerful by unfair means like fraud/scam etc. As a result, many people in the path of Dharma are not able to compete with them. It tempts good people to follow adharma path in order to succeed.

How does Hindu religion explain it? I heard in Kali Yuga only 25% is dharma (i.e one leg of the bull of dharma is left rest 3 are chopped off).  How long does it take to get the effect of the bad work?

Comment: The effect of bad work is immediate as tension and other things like avidya or ahamkar etc.. but still the bad fruits to be completely ripe you need to wait for the good karma to be exausted , its like credit and debit from your bank balance, with negative balance you are having bad experiences (sometimes god gives you bad experiences to lead you to correct path).